# Searching for indices of consecutive elements in an array

Tags: arrays, perl, search, element

So I have an array `my @a = (a,b,c,d,e,f)`
And another array `my @b = (c,d,e)`

I want to find if there are three consecutive elements in `@a` that match those in `@b`.
Then, if there are, I want to get the indices those elements live in.

So in the case above I want to get an array such as `(2,3,4)`.

Another example:
`my @a = (1,2,3,4,5)`
`my @b = (2,3)`

Output: `(1,2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general solution.  This uses the 'all' function, from List::MoreUtils to reduce the comparison to a true/false result, which simplifies the logic a little.

I put it into the form of a sub to which you pass a reference to any two arrays.  The first array ref passed to the function should be the superset, and the second array ref should refer to the subset array.

What I like about this solution is that it can apply to any two simple arrays (it isn't constrained to seeking a two-element subset, for example).  I did choose a string comparison of the elements (eq) as opposed to numeric (==).  That way it works if you have non-numeric elements.  However, it will evaluate '00' and '0' as non-equal (because they're not the same string).  If you favor a numeric comparison, just find the 'eq' and change it to '=='.

Here's the code:

```
use 5.010_001;
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw/all/;

my @array_a = qw/1 2 3 4 5/;
my @array_b = qw/2 3/;

{
    local $, = " ";
    my( @results ) = find_group( \@array_a, \@array_b );
    say "Success at ", @results if @results;
}


sub find_group {
    my( $array_1, $array_2 ) = @_;
    foreach my $array_1_idx ( 0 .. $#{$array_1} ) {
        my $moving_idx = $array_1_idx;
        return $array_1_idx .. ( $moving_idx - 1 ) if 
            all { $_ eq $array_1->[$moving_idx++] } @{$array_2};
    }
    return ();
}
```

Comment: Should probably return an empty list on failure

Comment: Great thought.  I applied your suggestion.

Comment: This is quite readable. I like it! I didn't know about the all function or the List module. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 4):

A naive approach:

```
@A = 1..5;
@B = 2..3;
A_LOOP:
for my $a_index (0..$#A) {
    for my $b_index (0..$#B) {
        next A_LOOP unless $A[$a_index+$b_index] eq $B[$b_index];
    }
    @results = map $a_index+$_, 0..$#B;
    last;
}
```

If this isn't fast enough (unlikely, given your examples), [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) isn't that difficult to implement.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. Follow up question though. How would you use @results after that?

So after your last curly brace if I were to add print @results; It would blow up with "global symbol requires explicit package."

How do you pass a result from inside the loop so that it is accessible outside of it?

Comment: @Yarian: declare it before the loops: `my @results;`